# How include pdf file in popup page how html element

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, popup

How to include a pdf file on a popup page as an html element.

I do not want to display as an embed or a picture, and I want to apply styles etc to the content of the PDF

Is there a plugin or similar for this?

Comment: Hello, ok, but i ask for displayed it without iframe or embed, thanks

Comment: That was not clear at all. You cannot display a PDF without using embed iframe etc

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps, I did not correct wrote the question. I paraphrase. But pdf can be parsed into html components and maybe there are some other JS plugins for this, for example pdf.js.

Comment: I found answer. We have to use pdf converter in html. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to delete the question